# Double forward slash in url, help in SEO?

Tags: seo, url, copyright, local-seo

I'm having a SEO optimised 7 year old website which rank no. 1 on google for different keywords.

Pages are www.example.com/page1.php , www.example.com/page2.php .

A competitor copied whole website and with few added pages uploaded a website on a very old domain like this;

www.xyz.com/somepages.html  and www.xyz.com//page1.html www.xyz.com//page2.html

He is not using any title and related tags just copied content exactly with same images and all, means only layout is different, otherwise its exactly same website.

Now does I need to let google know this is my content etc? Does it effects my ranking as today i'm on no. 1 and he is on 15th.

Most important question is why he is using two forward slash and .html extension? .html i can understand that someone may think that .html is more beneficial than .php for seo but why //?

Any qlue?

Comment: As for the duplicate content, it is important that if your content is uniquely yours, you file a DMCA complaint with Google here: https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/dmca-dashboard Google does warn you to be careful of filing a claim, but the example they cite is extremely narrow in scope and very misleading. If the content is yours, file a complaint. You will need a Google Search Console account to do this. That will solve that problem. Cheers!!

Answer (score 1):

> ## What is double slash?
>
> That is an error in the programmers/developers code.
>
> For instance if you navigate to: `http://www.imywebsite.gov/sectionA/sectionB/section/page/` 
>   And then add a slash: `http://www.imywebsite.gov/sectionA/sectionB//section/page/`
>
> The exact same page will load in most modern browsers. This is something you want to fix. If you have the double slash it could confuse Google's web crawlers and make them think there is 2 versions of the page.
>   It also occurs when the server ignore the second slash.

## What does that mean?

In this case the fact that your competitor have his double slashed link is working in your advantage.
About the extensions I would recommend to hide your extension with `.htaccess` `mod Rewrite` it looks more comfortable for the users and you get a shorter link which is more comfortable for the SEO.